# How to Programmatically Remove A UIImageView By touchGesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Ok, so I have been looking forever on how to use UITouchGestures with UIImageViews to remove the View, but everything either didn't make sense or didn't work so I finally decided to ask the question. How do you use A UITapGestureRecognizer to remove a UIImageView when it is tapped?

This is my .m:

```
       - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];


//this makes a zombie/person
UIImageView *ZombieView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(135 , -100, 50, 75)];
UIImage *Zombie=[UIImage imageNamed:@"free-vector-stick-figure-clip-art_105575_Stick_Figure_clip_art_hight.png"];
[ZombieView setImage:Zombie];
//[self.view addSubview:ZombieView];
[self.view insertSubview:ZombieView belowSubview:_Railing];
[ZombieView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

// double tap gesture recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *Touch2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped2:)];
[Touch2 setDelegate: self];
[Touch2 setNumberOfTapsRequired: 2];
[_ZombieView addGestureRecognizer:Touch2];


UITapGestureRecognizer *Touch = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:ZombieView action:@selector(tapped:)];
[Touch setDelegate:self];
[Touch setNumberOfTapsRequired: 1];
[Touch requireGestureRecognizerToFail: Touch2];
[_ZombieView addGestureRecognizer:Touch];

//This makes the Person move down until he is behind the railing
[UIView animateWithDuration:7.5
                    delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(ZombieView.transform, 0, 420);
                        ZombieView.transform=trans;
                    }
                 completion:nil];}

-(void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
[_ZombieView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void) tapped2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I know it must be a disaster, but I am fairly new to this so please keep this in mind. I just need know how to use the Tap Recognizers and how to delete a UIImageView, but other tips are appreciated. Thank you!

This is my edited code:

```
@interface AbcViewController ()

@end

@implementation AbcViewController




 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];



//this makes a zombie/person
UIImageView *zombieView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(135 , -100, 50, 75)];
UIImage *zombie=[UIImage imageNamed:@"free-vector-stick-figure-clip-art_105575_Stick_Figure_clip_art_hight.png"];
[zombieView setImage:zombie];
//[self.view addSubview:zombieView];
[self.view insertSubview:zombieView belowSubview:_Railing];
[zombieView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

//This makes the Person move down until he is behind the railing
[UIView animateWithDuration:7.5
                    delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(zombieView.transform, 0, 420);
                        zombieView.transform=trans;
                    }
                 completion:nil];


// double tap gesture recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *touch2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped2:)];
[touch2 setDelegate: self];
[touch2 setNumberOfTapsRequired: 2];
[zombieView addGestureRecognizer:touch2];


UITapGestureRecognizer *touch = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:zombieView action:@selector(tapped:)];
[touch setDelegate:self];
[touch setNumberOfTapsRequired: 1];
[touch requireGestureRecognizerToFail: touch2];
    [zombieView addGestureRecognizer:touch];


}

-(void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
   [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void) tapped2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

[recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
}



-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tap gesture recognizer has a view property that points to the view it's attached to. So, in the action method for the recognizer, use it to remove itself from its superview,

```
-(void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
[recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It's hard to tell why your method isn't working. It could be because _ZombieView is nil (I don't see anywhere you actually create _ZombieView as opposed to ZombieView which you do create). BTW, you should start your property and variable names with a lowercase letter to conform to the usual objective-c naming conventions.

Comment: I tried this and then I got the same error, 0_pthread_kill in Thread 1: SIGART. Do you have any suggestions? (I was getting this whenever I clicked or tapped the person.)

Comment: @user3447979, I think this might be because _Zombie view doesn't exist (and that's the view you attached the gesture recognizer to). Change the 2 lines where you add the gesture recognizer to the view, to have ZombieView instead of _ZombieView.

Comment: I was looking into this some more and found in the debugging bar that the error is with the argv character in int main. It says: **argv = (char) '/' does that mean anything. Oh and I now changed my names to the usual Obj-c naming conventions, for example ZombieView is zombieView. I was also doing some testing and it seems my UIGestureRecognizer isn't calling (void) tapped:.

Comment: @user3447979, if you haven't changed anything in the Main function, then you shouldn't worry about that error. That error usually crops up when you try to access a deallocated object. You should edit the code in your question to show what you have now - I don't know what you've changed and what you haven't.

Comment: Here is my edited code. I believe that there is something wrong with the gesture recognizer because my breakpoints aren't stopping the program at tapped and tapped2.

Comment: @user3447979, You might try touching the screen where the zombieView originally was before you do the transform, and see if tapped: and tapped2: are fired then. I seem to remember seeing this problem before with transformed views. I would suggest that you move the view by animating its frame, if you're not using auto layout, or one of its constraints if you are (instead of doing transforms).

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me the error again. The error is in the thread 1, it is: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and it has to do with the argv variable in the int main.

Comment: @user3447979, Change the target for touch from zombieView to self. I tried your code, and changing that made the method work as it should.